# Оповещение клиента с сервера

Tags: 1с

Если ли какие-нибудь токовые компоненты, чтобы реализовать подобную схему
Т.е. в чем суть:

Клиенты подключаются к 1С через **серверное соединение** или через **WEB сервер**

- Сервер знает, что клиент подключен и держит какой-нибудь канал с
  каждым клиентом
- При необходимости сервер посылает пакет клиенту, клиент получает и
  обрабатывает (только в том случаи если сервер посылает пакеты данных)
- Пакет данных содержит только строковое значение (т.е. тип значения
  строка)

Получается нужно как бы реализовать такой механизм чтобы сервер сообщал клиенту, но не через `СообщениеПользователю.Сообщить()` или `Сообщить()` , а именно передать параметр

[image: Примерная схема реализации]

Читал про

> 1С:Взаимодействия

но 1С так и не выпускает данный механизм, когда выпустят тоже не известно.

Реализация на `регистрах сведений` или через `фоновое задание` или методом `ПодключитьОбработчикОжидания` – не пойдёт

Буду очень признателен за направления или подсказки

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации такого механизма в принципе не сильно подходит использование платформы 8.3.11, то, что предлагают разработчики (система взаимодействия) ничем не отличается от `регистрах сведений` или через `фоновое задание` или методом `ПодключитьОбработчикОжидания`.
Возможно, они улучшат систему взаимодействий, но пока, увы, согласно доступной документации функционал пока не дотягивает.

Пока единственное решение это использовать компоненты `NativeAPI` и обрабатывать внешние события, как вариант можно использовать для этого очереди на `RabbitMQ`. Клиенты будут выступать в роли `consumers`, при авторизации подписываться на необходимые очереди событий.

Comment: RabbitMQ - Вроде как платный.

Comment: Система взаимодействий вообще сырая. Я тестировал её, как обсуждение объектов или создавать конференцию. Вот бы добавили события к объекту СистемаВзаимодействия (ПриПолученииСообщения) - подобие ПриСозданииНаСервере (типа слушателя)

Comment: @АлександрЗарифулли - платный? кто Вам сказал такую глупость? rabbitmq.com - и вперед!